# jQuery: Accordion - if hidden, show, else hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Trying to do an accordion for practice. I'm trying to write a really short code. the accordion has headers and a content. when clicked on the headers, the content should hide or show, depending on their visibility.

Any input would be great. thanks guys

Edit: I'm trying to avoid using .toggle

***NOTE***  accordion-content is hidden via css.

```
function open( accordion ) {

    $(".accordion-content").show(100);

}

function close ( accordion ) {

    $(".accordion-content").hide(100);

}

$(".accordion").click(function() {

    if ( $(".accordion-content:hidden")) {
        open();
    }

    else {
        close();    
    }

});
```

Should I add an if clause to the second part of the conditional? So it'd be like this:

```
else if ( $(".accordion-content:visible")) { 
    close();
}
```

Comment: which library you use to perform hide/show with microseconds?

Comment: can you please add your html code or create one fiddle example?

Comment: @jQuery, looks like jQuery for me, as it is tagged with jQuery too

Comment: @empiric   hide(100) . this will work only if jquery-ui added to page

Comment: @jQuery according to the jQuery-Docs this works with the core, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n1mj7rer/) here, [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/): `A string or number determining how long the animation will run.`

Comment: @empiric yes you are right sorry . i misunderstand document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of ..

```
$(".accordion-content:hidden")
```

Do:

```
$(".accordion-content").is(':hidden')
```

There really is no need for the last, "visible", option since you use "else". But if you want to use it then:

```
$(".accordion-content").is(':visible')
```

Comment: everyone thank you for the help! This happens to work. i do have a question though. why does .is(":hidden") work while not using .is does not? doesn't both check to see if the accordion is hidden or visible?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED to match your function names

Here is a common way to achieve this kind of behaviour. It can be usefull for other things that accordion.

Let say, with have a list of items, very similar, and we want only one of them to be highligted (here, one to be visible)

1-> Give all the items a common selector. Basically, a class. This class doesn't need to have attached css rule. It's just a selector. For this example, `.accordion`

2-> Bind your items with something unique. Here, You don't need this because the header is already a part of the panel.

3-> On activation (click, or something else that trigger the thing). 
    -deactivate all items that have the common class
    -activate the current item

that will give you something like

```
$(".accordion").on("click",function(){
    $(".accordion").not(this).close();
    $(this).open();
});
```

the close and open must look for a `accordion-content` inside the `accordion` element, and will show or hide it...

By the way, your `open` and `close` functions are false. It should be

```
$(this).find(".accordion-content").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
$(".accordion").click(function() {
   $(".accordion-content").toggle(100);
}
```

### EDIT

As you don't want toggle

```
$(".accordion").click(function() { 
  var cur_cont = $(this).find(".accordion-content"); 
  $(cur).show(100); 
  $(".accordion-content").not(cur_cont).hide(100); 
}
```

Comment: Simple, may work. But some accordion are closed by default. All closed. This solution can't work in those cases

Comment: Hope this helps , assuming you have used .accordion for header and .accordion-content for content for that header .

    $(".accordion").click(function() {
       var cur_cont =  $(this).find(".accordion-content");
       $(cur).show(100);
       $(".accordion-content").not(cur_cont).hide(100);
      }

It would be nice if you can provide code at jsfiddle for this.